# How can i get the current weekday beginning in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

For example today is 28/07/2011 
How do i get the weeks first day the monday which is 25/07/2011 in ruby

Comment: ...or the week's first day, the Sunday! ;-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
>> Date.today.beginning_of_week.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
#=> 25/07/2011
```

See the [Time](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/) and [Date](http://apidock.com/rails/Date/) classes under Rails for more info, and [strftime](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime) for information on the formatting options.

Comment: How can i format that to look 25/07/2011 ? Also do you know how do i get the beginning week in javascript with datepicker

Comment: Edited in formatting. Afraid I can't help you with the javascript though.

Comment: I'll note that this a great solution so long as you have ActiveSupport (in Rails), which it sounds like you do. Otherwise, you'll need to follow @Phrogz's [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858908/how-can-i-get-the-current-weekday-beginning-in-ruby/6859418#6859418) below.

Answer (score 29):

Without Rails/ActiveSupport:

```
phrogz$ irb
> require 'date'
> now = Date.today
#=> #<Date: 2011-07-28 (4911541/2,0,2299161)>
> sunday = now - now.wday
#=> #<Date: 2011-07-24 (4911533/2,0,2299161)>
> monday = now - (now.wday - 1) % 7
#=> #<Date: 2011-07-25 (4911535/2,0,2299161)>
> monday.iso8601
#=> "2011-07-25"
> monday.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
#=> "25/07/2011"
```

For more, see the [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html) class in the Standard Library.

Wrapped up as a method:

```
require 'date'
# For weekdays to start on Monday use 1 for the offset; for Tuesday use 2, etc.
def week_start( date, offset_from_sunday=0 )
  date - (date.wday - offset_from_sunday)%7
end

sun = Date.parse '2011-07-24'
week_start(sun,0).strftime('%a, %b-%d')  #=> "Sun, Jul-24"
week_start(sun,1).strftime('%a, %b-%d')  #=> "Mon, Jul-18"
```

Comment: this doesn't work for Sundays, as you end up having monday... after the sunday.
instead of 
now - now.wday + 1 I would go in 2 lines like:
shift = (now.wday == 0) ? 6 : (now.wday - 1) and then 
monday = date - shift

Comment: @DaleCooper Ack, thank you for the bug report. You're totally right. It can be simpler than that, though. I've edited my answer with a corrected version.